# react-rails React.renderToString is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

We are using react-rails gem v1.10.0 to incorporate react in our rails app. The `renderToString` method is used in order to create a popover effect as such

```
popover = React.createElement Popover, user: @props.user, avatar: @imageSrc()
React.renderToString(popover)
```

however I am getting a `Uncaught TypeError: React.renderToString is not a function`

This used to work fine but I think I'm getting the error now because `renderToString` is under [RenderDOMServer](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html). Unfortunately, when I try

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)
```

I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOMServer is not defined`

How do I get ReactDOMServer in the application so I can use the `renderToString` method?

Comment: you have to also include ReactDOMServer in the rails config. I think it should go here `app/assets/vendor/` per the docs https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/blob/master/VERSIONS.md#bundled-versions

Comment: @BrianMcCall I tried adding it from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/ however I get a different error within the react-dom-server.min.js file

Comment: what does your rails config look like?

Comment: We used `renderToString` only to render small things like links with interpolated props. We simply replaced them with CoffeeScript interpolation. E.g. `foo = """<a href="#{@props.thePath}">#{theText}</a>"""`